# How to use websocket with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

First time learning ReactJS, following official docs and learnt how the components works and Now I wanted to connect with websockets and trouble starts here. Why is this so hard to implement ?

```
// ReactJS
ReactDOM.render(
  <div className="media">
    <img className="media-figure" src={"kitten.jpg"}  width="48" height="48" />
    <p className="media-body">Hello</p>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('chat-list')
);


// Socket connection
socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/echo");

socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert(e.data);
}
socket.onopen = function() {
    socket.send("hello world");
}
// Call onopen directly if socket is already open
if (socket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) socket.onopen();
```

All I want is, when `onmessage` I need to render that `media` div.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `ReactDOM.render` method inside the `socket.onmessage` callback.

For bigger applications I recomend using Flux-based architecture as React team recomends. One of the most popular implementation is Redux which is quite easy to learn and use.
You can find more information on the Overview page of the Flux (I recomend their video):
https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html